# How to center a Flex list container with wrap and justify to flex-start elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some issues implement Flex-box, in my requirement for a view I have a list of cards, each card has a default width and height. I can use flex box and I prefer it.
When the elements of the list don't fit in the row, they should wrap in a new one, always from the left to the right, and all the list be centered in the available space of the container.

Here is [**a plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uXh4zf?p=preview) of the layout and **the code**:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">someItem01</div>
    <div class="item">someItem02</div>
    <div class="item">someItem03</div>
    <div class="item">someItem04</div>
    <div class="item">someItem05</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**This is what I'm trying to achieve:** 
[image]

**And this is what I currently have:**
[image]

How can I achieve the this without recurring to bunch of media queries, hard-coded margin/padding, etc?

Comment: I am a little unsure of "always from the left to the right, and all the list be centered" have you tried instead of `justify-content: flex start` using `justify-content: center` EDIT::: Ahhh I see you want them to be centered but still left aligned.

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem, to have them align to the left but the container centered in the space like they where `justify-content: center`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a very neat HTML, but you can achieve this result with some filler elements:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 12px;
}

.filler {
  width: 200px;  
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">someItem01</div>
    <div class="item">someItem02</div>
    <div class="item">someItem03</div>
    <div class="item">someItem04</div>
    <div class="item">someItem05</div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the easiest way I've found to deal with this issue.

Comment: very cool solution... but I guess that there are chances that we will have to add in more 'fillers' as the width of the screen increases...

Comment: This actually helps a lot, if I remove the margin top/bottom of the example fillers and add enough of them the display works as expected. Thank you very much.
If anyone can think on a Solution which doesn't requires unnecessary HTML will be awesome

Comment: @Matho, flexbox is not designed to be a grid system. It's a tool for aligning content and distributing space in a container. That's why a hack is necessary in this case. If you want a reliable grid there's always tables, [Desandro Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and, once it receives more browser support, [CSS Grids](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

Comment: @Michael_B yes, really this isn't a task for flex. Hopefully Grids will be available in the near future